# Re-create Code for SHOW PROFILES variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hi i am using MySQL,

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

Returns a long list, with rows like this for example:

```
 |Query_ID|Duration     |Query
>| 9    |    0.00028550 |   INSERT INTO Duration(Status,DURATION,Query_ID)|
```

I am trying to replicate this, so i can insert the results into a table and add a `WHERE` clause.

So i tried this

```
SELECT Query_ID, STATE, FORMAT(DURATION, 6) AS DURATION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING
WHERE QUERY_ID = 9;
```

But this  returns a lower level view(Which i do not want):

> starting  0.000053 Opening tables 0.000088

Which is the same as:

```
SHOW PROFILE;
```

How would i recreate `SHOW PROFILES`? 
So i can perform something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Duration(Query_ID,Status,DURATION)
SELECT * FROM SHOW PROFILE
WHERE PROFILE.QUERY_ID = 9;
```

Thanks

Comment: The output of `SHOW PROFILES` doesn't include a `Status` column, so what are you seeking to return here?  In my answer, I return the most recently completed server state for that query.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, I am seeking to replicate the exact results of SHOW PROFILES; QUERY_ID, DURATION , QUERY. But i am not clear where or how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `QUERY_ID`.  To obtain the status, you want the `STATE` of the record with the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) `SEQ`; to obtain the duration, just sum the `DURATION` of each record in the group:

```
INSERT INTO Duration
  (Query_ID, Status, DURATION)
SELECT QUERY_ID, STATE, t.DURATION
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING JOIN (
  SELECT   QUERY_ID, MAX(SEQ) AS SEQ, SUM(DURATION) AS DURATION
  FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING
  WHERE    QUERY_ID = 9
  GROUP BY QUERY_ID  -- superfluous in the presence of the above filter
) t USING (QUERY_ID, SEQ)
```

Comment: Thanks! This does return the Query_ID and Duration i am looking for. But the QUERY column in SHOW PROFILES must be stored somewhere also?